# php mail not returning true or false, nor is it returning a specified message

Tags: php, forms, post

I am new to php and I am having issues with the php mail function. I am testing on a live server, not localhost. When I complete my form I get no response from the mail function. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
         <?php 
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))):

if (isset($_POST['fullname'])) { $fullname = $_POST['fullname']; }
if (isset($_POST['email'])) { $email = $_POST['email']; }
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) { $phone = $_POST['phone']; }
if (isset($_POST['form_message'])) {
 $form_message = filter_var($_POST['form_message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); }

$form_errors = false;

if( $fullname === '') :
    $form_errors = true;
    endif;

if ($form_message === '') :
    $form_errors = true;
    endif;

if (!$form_errors) :
    $to = "email@address.com";
    $subject = "From $fullname --VTS Specialist Contact Form";
    $message = "$form_message";

    $replyto = "From: $email \r\n" .
               "Reply-To: email@address.com";


    if(mail($to, $subject, $message)):
        $msg = "Thanks for reaching out to VTS Specialist, We will get back to you as soon as possible!";
    else:
        $msg = " Sorry your message could not be sent, try again.";
    endif; # mail form data

endif; #check for form errors

endif;

?>
```

Comment: Is your question that you're not getting output? Because you're not printing out `$msg`, you just declare it. Also prefer the standard `{` curly `}` block syntax instead of the alternative unless you have a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an echo statement at the bottom - as Mario mentions, you are only declaring it, you're not displaying it.

---

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message)):
    $msg = "Thanks for reaching out to VTS Specialist, We will get back to you as soon as possible!";
else:
    $msg = " Sorry your message could not be sent, try again.";
endif; # mail form data

echo $msg;
```